# How to union two tables A and B but B has one column missing while the result should have all the columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have A table (P1, P2, P3) and B table (P1, P2), now I want to union them together. I know I can do something like

`SELECT P1, P2 FROM A 
UNION 
SELECT P1, P2 FROM B`

to merge all the rows. But in the result I have to get P3 too and for rows coming from B P3 should be null, how can I do this?

Comment: if it answers you question give it a green tick!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(SELECT P1, P2,P3 FROM A)
UNION ALL
(SELECT P1, P2,null FROM B)
```

check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32f84/2

Comment: @Wendy Huang if it answers you question give it a green tick!!!